# Подключить MariaDB на С++

Tags: c++, cmake, mariadb

IDE CLion может переходить в библиотеку `#include <mariadb/mysql.h>`, то есть, файл найден, однако проект не компилируется: `/home/nerd/CLionProjects/ISPstats/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to`mysql_init'`. Добавил в cmake

```
include_directories(/usr/lib/mysql mariadb)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mariadb)
```

Теперь программа, не дойдя до main, падает с сообщением Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV).

В чем может быть проблема и как подключить таки библиотеку?
Есть подозрение, что распаковывать файл коннектора MariaDB и кидать в /usr/lib/mysql было не очень хорошей идеей, но ничего другого придумать не могу.

Полный код приложения:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mariadb/mysql.h>
int main(){
    std::cout<<"start";
    MYSQL conn;
    std::cout<< "MYSQL conn;";
    if(!mysql_init(&conn)){
        std::cout<<"Error create MySQL descriptor";
    }
 if(!mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","stats","q1w2e3r4","statsDB",3306,NULL,0)){
        std::cout<<"Error connection";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(ISPstats)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")

endif()
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
include_directories(/usr/lib/mysql mariadb)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CONAN_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mariadb)
```

Нашел пример [тут](https://github.com/viaduck/mariadbpp), однако CMake ругается на

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindMariaDBClient.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "MariaDBClient", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MariaDBClient"
  with any of the following names:

    MariaDBClientConfig.cmake
    mariadbclient-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "MariaDBClient" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "MariaDBClient_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "MariaDBClient" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been
```

Установлены mariadb-server, mariadb-client, libmariadb и libmariadb-dev, не знаю, что еще можно сделать.

Comment: Попробуй подключить ещё сишный mysql. Как-то подключал сам. Либо: mysqlcconnector -> mariadbconnector, либо: mysqlcconnector -> mysqlcppconnector -> mariadbconnector. Как-то так.

Comment: Где вы взяли этот коннектор? Где происходит падание (какой стек вызовов и состояние переменных)?

Comment: Этот коннектор с сайта mySQL, а падение я даже не знаю,как поймать, если управление в main не заходит

Comment: Падение происходит в mysql_init, то есть, cmake уже не ругается, но приконектить либу не смог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примеры коннектора mariadb лежат [тут](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c). Собираю examples, после команды cmake нужно найти файл CMakeFiles/mysql_debug.dir/link.txt и заменить lmysql.h на -lmariadb. Судя по данному решению, если бы я использовал mySQL, такой проблемы бы не было

Answer (score 1):

Как говорится в документации, это делается через g++:

```
g++ -o tasks main.cpp -std=c++11 -lmariadbcpp
```

В CMakeFiles это добавляется следующим образом:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -lmariadbcpp")
```

Но увы, это может не сработать. Так как файл libmariadbcpp.so может не находится там, где его проверяет компилятор.

Узнать список мест, где он ищет можно следующей командой:

```
ld -lmariadbcpp --verbose
```

Лично у меня на archlinux файл лежал здесь:

```
/usr/lib/mariadb/libmariadbcpp.so
```

Я просто сделал символическую ссылку на него:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mariadb/libmariadbcpp.so /usr/lib/libmariadbcpp.so
```